# Delete the link to the image if it is the AMP version of the page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, amp-html

In the main version of my site, all images are framed with a link to a large image, like this: `<a href="link"><img src="url" /></a>`. But there is an AMP version of the site where I would like to display only an image without a link `<img src="url" />`.

Website on wordpress. The AMP version uses a plugin «AMPforWP» https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/

p.s. I apologize for my poor English)

Comment: You need to use AMP elements, such as `<amp-img>`. See https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-img/

Comment: Hi, Not sure what exactly is you question here. In AMP or in other sites as well you can remove <img > tag from anchor tag there is no such restriction for an img tag to exist. In amp site you need to add images with <amp-img> component. For more details check in components section of amp website to get other attribute details.